# Shoppingcart system from GET to AJAX post/get

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, get, cart

I made a shopping cart for a website using PHP .GET Like this:

Every page starts with:

```
<?php session_start(); 
    require("dbconnect.php");
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
         $cart = array();
         $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
     }  
?>
```

Every product that is generated has the following check when generated on the website:

```
if(!in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
    echo '<a href="'.get_site_url(). '/sem?action=add&id=' .$id. '#wpc-products"><img width="20px" style="margin-left: 175px;  margin-top: -42px; float:left" src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/voeg-toe.png" alt="Voeg product toe"/></a>';
    }
else {
    echo '<a href="'.get_site_url(). '/sem?action=delete&id=' .$id. '#wpc-products"><img width="20px" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-top: -42px; float:left"  src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/verwijderen.png" alt="Verwijder product"/> </a>';
    }
```

What it does: if the product with ID `$id` is in the `$_SESSION['cart']` the product will have a delete button which onclick deletes the product. When the product is not in the session cart the product will have an 'add' button which adds the product if you click on it.

This all works perfectly fine however, I want to change this PHP `GET`method to an AJAX GET function because the reloading of the page seems a bit amateurish.

So I searched on Google but all I found when searching for something like this is directly implementable AJAX code for Magento or WooCommerce. I tried to write my own AJAX function to execute the URL but I haven't managed so far. Can somebody give me a direction on how to do this? I am not asking for a direct solution but just for a direction on what way to do this.

Should I write an AJAX function which I add as onclick on a button to every product something like `function cart(id) {` that checks if the `id` is in the PHP cart or should I handle this way different? Do I still use the PHP Cart like how I made it right now or should I change that to a JavaScript array?

PS: I'm ok in PHP but a complete noob in JavaScript but I really want to learn some of it.

EDIT: Ok, so my first step to solve this is using jQuery.ajax(). But I could use both the jQuery $.get() and $.post() method. I know the differences between them in PHP but I'm not sure which one to use while using AJAX.

Comment: Have you considered jQuery? It's the most popular javascript library. Start googling `jQuery.ajax()`, you just need a URL and an idea of what to write in javascript after the data is returned from the server. `jQuery.ajax({url: *your_url*, success: function(returned_data){ *your code to handle returned data* })`

Comment: @Fredster I had considered it however, I was not confident that it was a good way to solve my problem. I will read the documentation and try to implement it myself.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your problem... however if the issue is that you're considering using raw javascript or jQuery to make and AJAX call (return data from the server and manipulating the page elements without reloading) - having had experience with both - I'd say learn jQuery, it's much easier, it's a popular well documented library, and you only have to load one library in your webpage.

Comment: @Fredster my problem is that I have now a fully working website but it uses PHP GET to add and delete items to the shoppingCart. I want to swap this to AJAX so that the webpages don't have to be reloaded on every 'add' or 'delete'. Since i'm new in jQuery/AJAX I'm asking for directions on how to solve this. Googling give me a lot of different approaches but I got a bit lost in all of the differences. The first advice to use jQuery.ajax() is a nice direction to search in!

Comment: You got two proposed code solutions! Check them out, and comment on the things you don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use AJAX like you said.Based on the code you provided

```
        if(!in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
    echo '<a class="add-to-cart-btn" data-id="'.$id.'" data-action="add"><img width="20px" style="margin-left: 175px;  margin-top: -42px; float:left" src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/voeg-toe.png" alt="Voeg product toe"/></a>';
    }
else {
    echo '<a class="add-to-cart-btn" data-id="'.$id.'" data-action="delete"><img width="20px" style="margin-left: 175px; margin-top: -42px; float:left"  src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/verwijderen.png" alt="Verwijder product"/> </a>';
    }
```

Then use jQuery to handle every click on anchor links having `add-to-cart-btn` class,get the id and the action you want (if it is not already in the cart add else delete), and use AJAX to send them to server.

```
$(".add-to-cart-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    var action=$(this).data('action');
    var this_button=$(this);

$.ajax({
            url: "/sem?action="+action+"&id="+id,
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                     //you can check your returned data from php here 
                     //and on success toggle data action (because user may click the button again...

                      this_button.data('action', action == 'add' ? 'delete' : 'add');

                    }
            });
          });
```

Of course the example is really basic.I have not tested it but something like this should do what you want.You should look up the documentation for `ajax` call so you can see all the options you have,handle errors etc.

Comment: Ok, I fixed some stuff and the add function already works! Super thanks for your answer, I'm working on the toggle function now and the delete function doesn't work yet. But the links work!

Answer (score 1):

I think your code could look something like this..

- write a PHP page that returns the `$_SESSION` variable in JSON (javascript object notation).

Example URL: shopping_cart_items.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require("dbconnect.php");
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Then get the data with jQuery:

```
// Gets (JSON) a Javascript Object from  the server
jQuery.getJSON("shopping_cart_items.php",function(items_in_shopping_cart){
    // Loops through all the <a> elements with class shopping_cart_elements
    // (assuming your <a> elements have a distinctive attribute such as a class "shopping_cart_elements")
    jQuery("a.shopping_cart_elements").each(function(index,dom_object){
            // Gets the current <a> element id attribute
            current_dom_obj_id = jQuery(dom_object).attr('id');

            // Checks if current id belongs to the array current_dom_obj_id
            if(items_in_shopping_cart.indexOf(current_dom_obj_id) != -1)
                // Changes the 'href' attribute to'action=add'
                jQuery(dom_object).attr('href','/sem?action=add&id='+id+ '#wpc-products');
            else
                // Changes the 'href' attribute to'action=delete'
                jQuery(dom_object).attr('href','/sem?action=delete&id='+id+ '#wpc-products');

        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm cringing a bit because somebody else gave a whole lot different solution (see below). Now I'm STILL not sure which one would work best/easiest for me. Can you explain to me why your solution is better or if not, why not?

Comment: My answer was more a show of `jQuery` functions you'll  most likely use. it is not a complete answer... the answers are similar, we both use jQuery to get AJAX, I use the simplified `.getJSON()` method, he uses `.ajax()`; he assumes the user will click a button and then javascript loads AJAX data and changes the button state, I assume upon page load javascript loads the data for all the buttons in the page, and change the button `href` attribute depending on wether or not the button `id` attribute belongs the the returned `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: It all depends on what you want.My code uses AJAX everytime a user clicks the add or delete button in order to add or delete an item from cart without page refresh(of course in order to work you should also change the php code beign called ,`/sem` in our case) .Fredster uses javascript to get the cart contents from the server and dynamically change the href attributes of the buttons(something you now do with the php code you provided,using an if statetement).It all depends how you want to implement your cart.

Comment: Used this method as first. The JSON part works and I tried to change the `<a>` element to `<a class="shopping_cart_elements" id="'.$id.'"` However, the link is not clickable. I tried adding an empty `href=""` so that the jQuery could change it(?) but that also didn't work. So now when you click the link, nothing happens. For a visualisation check: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/

Comment: Try putting href='javascript:void(0)' which is like an empty value but still make it a valid <a>.

Comment: Tried it, i'm not really sure how I should place this code, is it possible to make it one big function which I execute onclick on the link because the way I did it right now doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, create a <button onclick="make_ajax_call()">button</button>. And wrap the code around function make_ajax_call() { ... }. Is it not working? Can you see the errors in the console?

Comment: I'm sorry for being a noob, but I'm not getting what you meant by your last comment. Do I need to wrap the button around the current link system? I made a function make_ajax_call() with all the jQuery to execute in it. But how do I manage to let that jQuery to change the href and background of the button or `<a href=...` ?

Comment: Sorry, I expressed it poorly. Yes, that's it, the jQuery code inside the function. When you click the button (<button onclick=".."></button>) it will trigger the function make_ajax_call() because it is written in the attribute onclick=".." as I mentioned above.

Comment: You can see javascript errors in console if you're using Google Chrome / Safari / Firefox. They help you debug your javascript code. In Chrome in the menu bar press "View" - "Developer" - "Javascript Console"

Comment: Ah thanks! Fixed some minor issues already, WordPress did not support just .getJSON("shopping_cart_items.php") because it changes all the URLS to the frontpage (unless you specify the exact location of a js doc) so I did that. Now the only error that is left is: Uncaught TypeError: items_in_shopping_cart.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Ah, good. That means items_in_shopping_cart is not an array, i.e. you're probably not getting the correct data from the server. In the console, there is a tab called network, that shows the data you get in AJAX. After you click the <button> a new line named "shopping_cart_items.php" or something should show what your browser got.

Comment: Ok, somehow it went wrong on caching and I disabled it. I still have the same error, but at least the shopping_cart_items.php is found now. This looks like an array to me: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/shopping_cart_items.php  right...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117015/discussion-between-totalcare-and-fredster).

Comment: ahh ok, good! yes, it's an array but an empty one. Maybe the `$_SESSION` variable is empty?

Comment: Hi @Fredster I managed to fix it using the code of George Pant with some small additions and a toggle class on the image. If you want, you can check it: www.bgc-testomgeving.nl I wanted to thank you again for your help! Much appreciated!